# Can I control access to certain extension functions in Saxon?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

The Saxon configuration allows to call `setAllowExternalFunctions()` to enable or disable calling external functions from stylesheets.

Is there a way to have more fine-grained control over this? My specific needs are wanting to white list a few functions, while blocking all the rest.

Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about reflexive extension functions, you can call

```
((ProfessionalConfiguration) config).setExtensionBinder("java", javaLib);
```

where javaLib is a class that extends `com.saxonica.config.JavaExtensionLibrary` and that overrides methods such as `bind()` and `getFunctionItem()` to check that the function name is OK, and then call `super()` if so.

Alternatively, prevent all calls to reflexive functions, and provide integrated extension functions to implement the things on your whitelist.